# Create OR Update Object in Parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am creating an Ionic app that is using Parse.com as its backend. I want to save an item to an existing Object however if it already exists then I want to Update the item. I have tried using the .save from the documentation however it constantly creates new rows.

I am able to query for the Existing ID using the following:

```
var ExisitingId = Parse.Object.extend("Exercises");
var query = new Parse.Query(ExisitingId);

query.equalTo("exerciseName", $scope.currentExcercise);
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    // alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
      var object = results[i];
      // alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('exerciseName already Exists'));
      var ExisitingIdNumber = object.id;
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

And this is my code that is used to create / save rows in the Object `Exercises`:

```
$scope.saveToParse = function(exercise) {

var Exercises = Parse.Object.extend("Exercises");
var exercises = new Exercises();

exercises.set({exerciseName: exercise.ExerciseName,
          exerciseID: exercise.ExerciseID,
          exerciseDescription: exercise.Description,
          sets: exercise.Sets,
          reps: exercise.Reps,
          resistance: exercise.Resistance,
          tempo: exercise.Tempo,
          images: $scope.images})

exercises.save(null, {
  success: function(exercises) {
    // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
    alert('Exercise saved with objectId: ' + exercises.id);
  },
  error: function(exercises, error) {
    // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
    alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
  }
});

}
```

I would ideally like to combines these two functions to check for existing value and then either create / update automatically.

Regards Simon

Answer (score 1):

Well this works...

```
$scope.saveToParse = function(exercise) {

var Exercises = Parse.Object.extend("Exercises");
var exercises = new Exercises();
exercises.id = $scope.ExisitingExerciseID;
console.log($scope.ExisitingExerciseID);

exercises.fetch()
.then(function(){
      exercises.set({exerciseName: exercise.ExerciseName,
          exerciseID: exercise.ExerciseID,
          exerciseDescription: exercise.Description,
          sets: exercise.Sets,
          reps: exercise.Reps,
          resistance: exercise.Resistance,
          tempo: exercise.Tempo,
          images: $scope.images})

      return exercises.save();
       $state.go('app.exercises', {clear: true});

})
}
```

Comment: Another way to do it is to query for every object with ExerciseID and if you get no results, create a new object.